# Snappy Ubuntu Core In Debain Qemu

Tags: emulation, ubuntu, qemu

Is there a way to emulate the Snappy Ubuntu Core image in Qemu under Debian now that it has an arm cortex a-7 chip on it?

I tried following [this wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/KVM) and installed virt-manager to set things up but I do not see the option for arm-cortex-a7 when I set click on the drop down menu for arm devices

Answer (score 0):

I have made it using cortex-a9 which is suitable for raspberry pi 2 (I have followed actually [this tutorial](https://electgon.com/publications/embedded-systems/realtime-snappy-emulation/))

so the command for that should be:

```
$qemu-system-arm -kernel vexpress_04_zImage -append "root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rw" -m1G -cpu cortex-a9 -M vexpress-a9 -sd pi-snappy.img
```

Which is I think should be fine nowadays